# Can python send text to the Mac clipboard

Tags: python, macos, clipboard

I'd like my python program to place some text in the Mac clipboard.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**New answer:**

[This page](http://www.devx.com/opensource/Article/37233/0/page/3) suggests:

> **Implementation for All Mac OS X
> Versions**
>
> The other Mac module
> (MacSharedClipboard.py, in Listing 4)
> implements the clipboard interface on
> top of two command-line programs
> called pbcopy (which copies text into
> the clipboard) and pbpaste (which
> pastes whatever text is in the
> clipboard). The prefix "pb" stands for
> "pasteboard," the Mac term for
> clipboard.

**Old answer:**

Apparently so:

http://code.activestate.com/recipes/410615/

is a simple script demonstrating how to do it.

Edit: Just realised this relies on Carbon, so might not be ideal... depends a bit what you're using it for.

Comment: I never thought of using a command line tool. Perfect, thanks

Comment: That code sample does not handle Unicode strings correctly. I have provided a Unicode-aware solution as a separate answer.

Answer (score 116):

How to write a Unicode string to the Mac clipboard:

```
import subprocess

def write_to_clipboard(output):
    process = subprocess.Popen(
        'pbcopy', env={'LANG': 'en_US.UTF-8'}, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
    process.communicate(output.encode('utf-8'))
```

How to read a Unicode string from the Mac clipboard:

```
import subprocess

def read_from_clipboard():
    return subprocess.check_output(
        'pbpaste', env={'LANG': 'en_US.UTF-8'}).decode('utf-8')
```

Works on both Python 2.7 and Python 3.4.

**2021 Update:** If you need to be able to read the clipboard on other operating systems and not just Mac and are okay with adding an external library, [pyperclip](https://pypi.org/project/pyperclip/) also seems to work well. I tested it on Mac with Unicode text:

```
python -m pip install pyperclip
python -c 'import pyperclip; pyperclip.copy("私はDavid!")'  # copy
python -c 'import pyperclip; print(repr(pyperclip.paste()))'  # paste
```

Comment: i have no idea why this one gets so little love, it's by far the most elegant and reliable method on this page

Comment: @DavidFoster I’m using pyperclip now and it seems to be conflicting with pyautogui.  Throws an Attribute Error regarding the pasteboard.  Have you ever run into this issue?  Seems like for me your first answer is the best at this point.  Here’s my post on github:  https://github.com/asweigart/pyperclip/issues/208

Answer (score 22):

A simple way:

```
cmd = 'echo %s | tr -d "\n" | pbcopy' % str
os.system(cmd)
```

A cross-platform way:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4203897/805627

```
from Tkinter import Tk
r = Tk()
r.withdraw()
r.clipboard_clear()
r.clipboard_append('i can has clipboardz?')
r.destroy()
```

Comment: Code block #1 probably does not work if the text to be written to the clipboard contains Unicode or shell characters like | or &. Code block #2 creates an extra dock icon on OS X. I've provided my own answer to this question which doesn't have these issues.

Comment: Too bad that the cross-platform way ... doesn't work reliably. And that you also missed the `r.update()` call that the original answer shows now.

Answer (score 19):

The following code use PyObjC (https://pyobjc.readthedocs.io)

```
from AppKit import NSPasteboard, NSArray

pb = NSPasteboard.generalPasteboard()
pb.clearContents()
a = NSArray.arrayWithObject_("hello world")
pb.writeObjects_(a)
```

As [explained in Cocoa documentation](http://web.archive.org/web/20091226153052/http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PasteboardGuide106/Articles/pbCopying.html), copying requires three step :

- get the pasteboard
- clear it
- fill it

You fill the pasteboard with an array of object (here `a` contains only one string).

Answer (score 6):

I know this is an older post, but I have found a very elegant solution to this problem.

There is a library named *PyClip*, which can be found at https://github.com/georgefs/pyclip-copycat.

The syntax is pretty simple (example from the Github repo):

```
import clipboard

# copy some text to the clipboard
clipboard.copy('blah blah blah')

# get the text currently held in the clipboard
text = clipboard.paste()
```

once you've passed `clipboard.copy('foo')` you can just **cmd + v** to get the text

Comment: I miss explaining the advantage of `clipboard` to [`pyperclip`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25802742/1705829) - see example here - which is needed by clipboard.

Answer (score 1):

if you just wanted to put text into the mac clipboard, you could use the shell's pbcopy command.

Comment: If it's a super-short python command, you can pipe the command's output to pbcopy like this: python -c "print 'hi'" | pbcopy. You can also include a bunch of consecutive commands: python -c 'import time,sys; sys.stdout.write(str(int(time.time())))' | pbcopy. This one copies the unix time without the trailing newline to the clipboard.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @David Foster's answer, I implemented a simple script(only works for mac) to decode python dict(actually, it is parsed from a JSON string) to JSON string, because sometimes when debugging, I need to find the mistake(s) in the data(and the data body is very big and complex, which is hard for human to read), then I would paste it in python shell and `json.dumps(data)` and copy to VS code, prettify the JSON. So, the script below would be very helpful to my works.

```
alias pyjson_decode_stdout='python3 -c "import sys, json, subprocess; \
    print(json.dumps(eval(subprocess.check_output( \
        \"pbpaste\", env={\"LANG\": \"en_US.UTF-8\"}).decode(\"utf-8\"))))"'
alias pyjson_decode='python3 -c "import json, subprocess; \
    output=json.dumps(eval(subprocess.check_output(\
        \"pbpaste\", env={\"LANG\": \"en_US.UTF-8\"}).decode(\"utf-8\"))).encode(\"utf-8\"); \
    process=subprocess.Popen(\"pbcopy\", env={\"LANG\": \"en_US.UTF-8\"}, stdin=subprocess.PIPE); \
    process.communicate(output)"'
```

add the script to `~/.zshrc` or `~/.bashrc` (based on which `sh` you use) and new a terminal window, the example usage is copy one dict data, e.g. `{'a': 1}` and enter `pyjson_decode_stdout` would print the parsed json based on this dict; Copy and enter `pyjson_decode` would write this string to `pbcopy`.