# How can I paste some string to the active window in Python?

Tags: python, windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I copy a string to the clipboard on Windows using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/579687/how-do-i-copy-a-string-to-the-clipboard-on-windows-using-python)

Can someone make me an example or explain to me how can I paste something to the active window with Python?

I've edited because I didn't know that paste to the clipboard doesnt paste to the active window...

Comment: Duplicate. see: - Windows: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/579687/how-do-i-copy-a-string-to-the-clipboard-on-windows-using-python - Mac: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825692/can-python-send-text-to-the-mac-clipboard - Linux: http://www.answermysearches.com/python-how-to-copy-and-paste-to-the-clipboard-in-linux/286/

Answer (score 3):

since you haven't accepted the duplicate as an answer may i suggest:

```
import win32com.client
shell = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")
shell.SendKeys('keys to send to active window...')
```

from:

[here](http://kvance.livejournal.com/985732.html)

and if you need to find out about keys like Backspace go to

[here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8c6yea83.aspx)