# Copying to OS Clipboard without importing (i.e. Clipboard, Pyperclip) in Python

Tags: python, clipboard

I need to figure out a way to apply a result to the system clipboard without installing any software (i.e. Clipboard, Pyperclip).

I've searched many topics on S.O. but it appears that all the solutions require installing Pyperclip or other third party software, is there a system script that can be created to copy to the clipboard without the use of these? It's a requirement that I not have any installations that are required to run my program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are on Windows you can use this script that uses just the standard `os` package

```
import os
text = 'abc'
command = 'echo ' + text.strip() + '| clip'
os.system(command)
```

[my source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9409898/2327328)

---

if you can use pandas library:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame(['Text to copy'])
df.to_clipboard(index=False,header=False)
```

[my source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36178407/2327328)

---

on a mac you can use this script

```
import subprocess
process = subprocess.Popen(
    'pbcopy', env={'LANG': 'en_US.UTF-8'}, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
process.communicate('abc'.encode('utf-8'))
```

[my source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25802742/2327328)

---

and on linux, this may work

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
p = Popen(['xsel','-pi'], stdin=PIPE)
p.communicate(input='Hello, World')
```

[my source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7606100/2327328)

---

and finally, if you don't know what operating system you are on, you can find out with a [code like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1857/2327328)

Comment: Apologies on the formatting, I am very new to this, but for some reason I can't get the code to format...


Here's what I tried:

#First line is within a function 
if sentinel_value == "=":
                copy(running_total)
                return running_total

def copy(solution_answer):
    clipboard_answer = str(solution_answer)
    command = 'echo ' + clipboard_answer.strip() + '| clip'
    print("\n\n\n\n", solution_answer, "has been copied to your clipboard")

However, nothing happens. The code runs, and I get my confirmation print statement, but nothing in my clipboard.

Comment: i've updated the windows example to run the command with `os.system(command)`

Comment: Thank you! That works! I +1'd you but it doesn't show because I don't have enough rep.

Answer (score 0):

If you are Using WSL or windows, you can also use

```
import subprocess

txt = "Copy to clipboard!"
subprocess.run(['clip.exe'], input=txt.strip().encode('utf-8'), check=True)
```