# What does the PB prefix stand for in many Mac APIs?

Tags: macos, api, terminology

I've been looking through some [old Mac programming references](http://mirror.informatimago.com/next/developer.apple.com/documentation/Carbon/Reference/CoreServicesReferenceCollection/CoreServicesReferenceCollection.pdf) and found quite a few sets of three APIs with naming patterns like these:

- `FSIterateForks`
- `PBIterateForksSync`
- `PBIterateForksAsync`

I'm pretty sure the `FS-` is for "filesystem". But I can't seem to find what the `PB-` is for. Note that it always seems to be together with one of the suffixes `-Sync` or `-Async`.

I don't think it's for "PowerBook" or "Petabyte" or "[pasteboard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1825723/527702)" in this case, though those all use the "pb" abbreviation in certain circumstances in the Apple world.

Could it stand for "Public Beta"? I think this was used for OSX before it was released? But it seems a bit odd to enshrine this in API names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging from the function signatures, it stands for “param block”:

```
extern OSErr  PBIterateForksSync(FSForkIOParam * paramBlock)  __OSX_AVAILABLE_BUT_DEPRECATED(__MAC_10_0, __MAC_10_8, __IPHONE_NA, __IPHONE_NA);
extern void  PBIterateForksAsync(FSForkIOParam * paramBlock)  __OSX_AVAILABLE_BUT_DEPRECATED(__MAC_10_0, __MAC_10_8, __IPHONE_NA, __IPHONE_NA);
```

All of these `PB` functions take a parameter called `paramBlock`.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. So the Parameter Block aka HFS Parameter Block is (or was??) an important structure in the File Manager. It's discussed throughout [this PDF on Apple's developer site](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/mac/pdf/Files/File_Manager.pdf): " The low-level routines generally provide the greatest control over the requested task; they are identified by the prefixes PB and PBH, indicating that they take the address of a parameter block as a parameter."