# Copy string - Python

Tags: python, string, copy, clipboard

Ok guys I imagine this is easy but I can't seem to find how to copy a string. Simply COPY to the system like CTRL+C on a text.

Basically I want to copy a string so I can for example, lets say, paste(ctrl+v).

Sorry for such a trivial question, haha.

Comment: dependent on operating system I would imagine, what are you using?

Comment: Windows, although I ask, what if the application was supposed to be multi-platform? Would there be a way?

Comment: Similar question with a bunch of good answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/579687

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I copy a string to the clipboard on Windows using Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/579687/how-do-i-copy-a-string-to-the-clipboard-on-windows-using-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends a lot on the OS. On Linux, due to X's bizarre selection model, the easiest way is to use `popen('xsel -pi')`, and write the text to that pipe.

For example: (I think)

```
def select_xsel(text):
    import subprocess
    xsel_proc = subprocess.Popen(['xsel', '-pi'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
    xsel_proc.communicate(some_text)
```

As pointed out in the comments, on a Mac, you can use the `/usr/bin/pbcopy` command, like this:

```
xsel_proc = subprocess.Popen(['pbcopy'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
```

If you want to support different OSes, you could combine different solutions with `os.name` to determine which method to use:

```
import os, subprocess
def select_text(text):
    if os.name == "posix":
        # try Mac first
        try:
            xsel_proc = subprocess.Popen(['pbcopy'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
        except:
            # try Linux version
            xsel_proc = subprocess.Popen(['xsel', '-pi'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
    elif os.name == "nt":
        # Windows...
```

Comment: on mac, do the same thing except with `/usr/bin/pbcopy`

Comment: Thanks for both replys & comments!

Answer (score 4):

For Windows, you [use win32clipboard](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/724).  You will need [pywin32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/).

For GTK (at least on GNU/Linux),  you can [use pygtk](http://www.answermysearches.com/python-how-to-copy-and-paste-to-the-clipboard-in-linux/286/).

EDIT: Since you mentioned (a bit late) you're using wxPython, they actually have a module for this too, [wx.Clipboard](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.Clipboard-class.html).

Comment: What if, the application was supposed to be multi-platform? Would it be possible?

Comment: I think you would have to test for platform and then do one of the methods mentioned here

Comment: GTK can run on Windows, so it's likely (but untested) you can use that on both platforms.  See http://www.pygtk.org/downloads.html and http://www.gtk.org/download-windows.html#StableRelease

Answer (score 2):

For Windows, you can do [this](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-win32/2003-October/001321.html) and it's much easier than creating a new subprocess etc...

Answer (score 2):

For a multi-platform solution you will need to use a cross-platform framework like wxPython or PyQt - they both have support for reading and writing to the system clipboard in a platform independent way.

Comment: Well ye I'm actually using wxPython.