# How to get selected text with xsel - Python

Tags: python, linux, selection, clipboard

I need a python script, which will get selected text in an other application with xsel, and then store it in a var.

Thanks

Comment: also take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614975/copy-string-python)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once you have the text you want selected, run this:

```
import os

var = os.popen('xsel').read()
print var
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm adding an additional answer based on the fact that `os.popen` is now considered obsolete. The following code is from the original answer (except variable naming changed for convenience):

```
out = os.popen("xsel").read()
```

Now we rewrite it using `subprocess.Popen` instead of `os.popen`:

```
process = subprocess.Popen("xsel", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
out = process.stdout.read()
```

It can be simplified as follows:

```
process = subprocess.Popen("xsel", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
out, err = process.communicate()
```

And the best at the end:

```
out = subprocess.check_output("xsel", universal_newlines=True)
```

The `universal_newlines` option, while the name doesn't suggest that, turns the input and output into text strings instead of byte strings, which are the default for `subprocess.Popen`.