# How can I paste some string to the active window in Python?

Tags: python, windows, sendkeys

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I copy a string to the clipboard on Windows using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/579687/how-do-i-copy-a-string-to-the-clipboard-on-windows-using-python)

Can someone make me an example or explain to me how can I paste something to the active window with Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easiest if you **use the [SendKeys](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/SendKeys) package**.  You can find a Windows installer for various Python versions [here](http://www.rutherfurd.net/python/sendkeys/#dowloads).

The simplest use case, sending plain text, is very simple:

```
import SendKeys
SendKeys.SendKeys("Hello world")
```

You can do all sorts of nifty things **using key-codes to represent for unprintable characters**:

```
import SendKeys
SendKeys.SendKeys("""
    {LWIN}
    {PAUSE .25}
    r
    Notepad.exe{ENTER}
    {PAUSE 1}
    Hello{SPACE}World!
    {PAUSE 1}
    %{F4}
    n
""")
```

**Read [the documentation](http://www.rutherfurd.net/python/sendkeys/) for full details.**

If for whatever reason you don't want to introduce a dependency on a non-standard library package, you can [do the same thing](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/65107-sendkeys-from-the-windows-script-host-wsh-com/) using COM:

```
import win32api
import win32com.client

shell = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")
shell.Run("calc")
win32api.Sleep(100)
shell.AppActivate("Calculator")
win32api.Sleep(100)
shell.SendKeys("1{+}")
win32api.Sleep(500)
shell.SendKeys("2")
win32api.Sleep(500)
shell.SendKeys("~") # ~ is the same as {ENTER}
win32api.Sleep(500)
shell.SendKeys("*3")
win32api.Sleep(500)
shell.SendKeys("~")
win32api.Sleep(2500)
```

Comment: Cannot be installed on on py3.6 win