# Is there a way to make the Tkinter text widget read only?

Tags: python, text, tkinter

It doesn't look like it has that attribute, but it'd be really useful to me.

Comment: A Tkinter `Entry` widget allows `entry.config(state='readonly')`. Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work for the `Text` widget.

Answer (score 119, accepted):

You have to change [the state](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm#patterns) of the `Text` widget from `NORMAL` to `DISABLED` **after** entering `text.insert()` or `text.bind()` :

```
text.config(state=DISABLED)
```

Comment: Then you can't select text, and copy it.

Comment: Selecting and copying (through CTRL-C in Windows and automatically in Linux) seem to work just fine for me.

Comment: @CraigMcQueen You can actually do it by binding the `<1>` with a function that sets the focus on the text widget: `text.bind("<1>", lambda event: text.focus_set())`.

Answer (score 51):

```
text = Text(app, state='disabled', width=44, height=5)
```

Before and after inserting, change the state, otherwise it won't update

```
text.configure(state='normal')
text.insert('end', 'Some Text')
text.configure(state='disabled')
```

Answer (score 38):

Very easy solution is just to bind any key press to a function that returns "break" like so:

```
import Tkinter

root = Tkinter.Tk() 

readonly = Tkinter.Text(root)
readonly.bind("<Key>", lambda e: "break")
```

Comment: uou! this is a nice one

Answer (score 25):

The [tcl wiki](http://wiki.tcl.tk/1152) describes this problem in detail, and lists three possible solutions:

1. The Disable/Enable trick described in other answers
2. Replace the bindings for the insert/delete events
3. Same as (2), but wrap it up in a separate widget.

(2) or (3) would be preferable, however, the solution isn't obvious. However, [a worked solution is available on the unpythonic wiki](http://tkinter.unpythonic.net/wiki/ReadOnlyText):

```
 from Tkinter import Text
 from idlelib.WidgetRedirector import WidgetRedirector

 class ReadOnlyText(Text):
     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
         Text.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
         self.redirector = WidgetRedirector(self)
         self.insert = self.redirector.register("insert", lambda *args, **kw: "break")
         self.delete = self.redirector.register("delete", lambda *args, **kw: "break")
```

Comment: What is `idlelib` and where does it come from? It would be good to have a solution that doesn't need an `idlelib` dependency.

Comment: On Ubuntu Linux, I can get `idlelib` by `sudo apt-get install idle-python2.7`

Comment: `idlelib` is part of the Python standard library. However, for some reason Ubuntu seems to enjoy packaging Python in lots of little parts.

Answer (score 11):

If your use case is really simple, [nbro's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3924118/nbro) `text.bind('<1>', lambda event: text.focus_set())` code solves the interactivity problem that [Craig McQueen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/60075/craig-mcqueen) sees on OS X but that others don't see on Windows and Linux.

On the other hand, if your readonly data has any contextual structure, at some point you'll probably end up using `Tkinter.Text.insert(position, text, taglist)` to add it to your readonly Text box window under a tag. You'll do this because you want parts of the data to stand out based on context. Text that's been marked up with tags can be emphasized by calling `.Text.tag_config()` to change the font or colors, etc. Similarly, text that's been marked up with tags can have interactive bindings attached using `.Text.tag_bind()`. There's a good example of using [these functions here](http://web.archive.org/web/20200806215420/http://effbot.org/zone/tkinter-text-hyperlink.htm). If a `mark_for_paste()` function is nice, a `mark_for_paste()` function that understands the context of your data is probably nicer.

Answer (score 8):

This is how I did it. Making the state disabled at the end disallows the user to edit the text box but making the state normal before the text box is edited is necessary for text to be inserted.

```
from tkinter import *
text=Text(root)
text.pack()
text.config(state="normal")
text.insert(END, "Text goes here")
text.config(state="disabled")
```

Answer (score 7):

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()
text = Text(root)
text.insert(END,"Some Text")
text.configure(state='disabled')
```

Comment: Then you can't select text, and copy it.

Comment: You can select text and copy also. It's working for me in windows

Comment: @CraigMcQueen - I'm pretty sure that this is handled internally regardless of the state. I don't know if you can disable selecting and copying, either.

Answer (score 5):

Use this code in windows if you want to disable user edit and allow <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> for copy on screen text:

```
def txtEvent(event):
    if(event.state==12 and event.keysym=='c' ):
        return
    else:
        return "break"

txt.bind("<Key>", lambda e: txtEvent(e))
```

Answer (score 4):

If selecting text is not something you need disabling the state is the simplest way to go. In order to support copying you can use an external entity - a `Button` - to do the job. Whenever the user presses the button the contents of `Text` will be copied to clipboard. `Tk` has an in-build support of handling the clipboard (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4203897/1559401)) so emulating the behaviour of `Ctrl-C` is an easy task. If you are building let's say a console where log messages are written you can go further and add an `Entry` where the user can specify the number of log messages he wants to copy.

Answer (score 4):

Many mentioned you can't copy from the text widget when the state is disabled. For me on Ubuntu Python 3.8.5 the copying issue turned out to be caused by the widget not having focus on Ubuntu (works on Windows).

I have been using the solution with setting the state to disabled and then switching the state, when I need to edit it programmatically using 1) text.config(state=tkinter.NORMAL) 2) editing the text and 3) text.config(state=tkinter.DISABLED).
On windows I was able to copy text from the widget normally, but on Ubuntu it would look like I had selected the text, but I wasn't able to copy it.

After some testing it turned out, that I could copy it as long as the text widget had focus. On Windows the text widget seems to get focus, when you click it regardless of the state, but on Ubuntu clicking the text widget doesn't focus it.

So I fixed this problem by binding the text.focus_set() to the mouse click event "<Button>":

```
import tkinter
root = tkinter.Tk()
text0 = tkinter.Text(root, state=tkinter.DISABLED)
text0.config(state=tkinter.NORMAL)
text0.insert(1.0, 'You can not copy or edit this text.')
text0.config(state=tkinter.DISABLED)
text0.pack()

text1 = tkinter.Text(root, state=tkinter.DISABLED)
text1.config(state=tkinter.NORMAL)
text1.insert(1.0, 'You can copy, but not edit this text.')
text1.config(state=tkinter.DISABLED)
text1.bind("<Button>", lambda event: text1.focus_set())
text1.pack()
```

For me at least, that turned out to be a simple but effective solution, hope someone else finds it useful.

Answer (score 3):

Disabling the Text widget is not ideal, since you would then need to re-enable it in order to update it. An easier way is to catch the mouse button and any keystrokes. So:

```
    textWidget.bind("<Button-1>", lambda e: "break")
    textWidget.bind("<Key>", lambda e: "break")
```

seems to do the trick. This is how I disabled my "line numbers" Text widget in a text editor. The first line is the more powerful one. I'm not sure the second is needed, but it makes me feel better having it there. :)

Comment: As a side note, disabling the left mouse button precludes one from clicking on and selecting the Text widget, which does most of the job. But disabling keys helps, too, in case the Text widget can be tabbed into or is given keyboard focus.

Answer (score 1):

This can also be done in Frames

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
area = Frame(root)
T = (area, height=5, width=502)
T.pack()
T.insert(1.0, "lorem ipsum")
T.config(state=DISABLED)
area.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Label instead. A Label can be edited programmatically and cannot be edited by the user.

Comment: You lose a *lot* of functionality when you do that.

Comment: @BryanOakley What functionality would you still need if it's intended to be used as read-only?

Comment: the ability to scroll and the ability to apply formatting to individual characters are the two biggest things you lose. Plus, you lose the ability to select text, and word wrapping in the text widget is much better than in a label.