# How to disable input to a Text widget but allow programmatic input?

Tags: python, tkinter, textbox, widget

How would i go about locking a `Text` widget so that the user can only select and copy text out of it, but i would still be able to insert text into the `Text` from a function or similar?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Have you tried simply disabling the text widget?

```
text_widget.configure(state="disabled")
```

On some platforms, you also need to add a binding on `<1>` to give the focus to the widget, otherwise the highlighting for copy doesn't appear:

```
text_widget.bind("<1>", lambda event: text_widget.focus_set())
```

If you disable the widget, to insert programatically you simply need to

1. Change the state of the widget to `NORMAL`
2. Insert the text, and then
3. Change the state back to `DISABLED`

As long as you don't call `update` in the middle of that then there's no way for the user to be able to enter anything interactively.

Answer (score 8):

Sorry I'm late to the party but I found this page looking for the same solution as you.

I found that if you "disable" the Text widget by default and then "normal" it at the beginning of a function that gives it input and "disable" it again at the end of the function.

```
def __init__():
    self.output_box = Text(fourth_frame, width=160, height=25, background="black", foreground="white")
    self.output_box.configure(state="disabled")

def somefunction():
    self.output_box.configure(state="normal")
    (some function goes here)
    self.output_box.configure(state="disable")
```

Answer (score 3):

I stumbled upon the state="normal"/state="disabled" solution as well, however then you are unable to select and copy text out of it.  Finally I found the solution below from: [Is there a way to make the Tkinter text widget read only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3842155/is-there-a-way-to-make-the-tkinter-text-widget-read-only), and this solution allows you to select and copy text as well as follow hyperlinks.

```
import Tkinter

root = Tkinter.Tk() 
readonly = Tkinter.Text(root)
readonly.bind("<Key>", lambda e: "break")
```

Comment: i don't know, but, although i can select text, i can't seem to copy from it.