# Display user input in Tkinter.Text area

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to get the user input from an entry box and once a button is pressed, display that in a tk.Text(). The reason I am not doing it in a label is because I'd like the gui looking something like this:

User: Hey

Response: What's up

User: Nothing..

I had a look at this documentation :http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm
And example uses [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3842155/is-there-a-way-to-make-the-tkinter-text-widget-read-only) but can't get mine to work.

```
result = None
window = Tk()

def Response():
    global result
    result = myText.get()

#The below print displays result in console, I'd like that in GUI instead.
    #print "User: ", result

#Creating the GUI
myText = tk.StringVar()
window.resizable(False, False)
window.title("Chatbot")
window.geometry('400x400')
User_Input = tk.Entry(window, textvariable=myText, width=50).place(x=20, y=350)
subButton = tk.Button(window, text="Send", command=Response).place(x =350, y=350)
displayText = Text(window, height=20, width=40)
displayText.pack()
displayText.configure(state='disabled')
scroll = Scrollbar(window, command=displayText).pack(side=RIGHT)
window.mainloop()
```

I have tried variations of;
`displayText.insert(window,result)` and `displayText.insert(End, result)`

But still get nothing when I submit the text. The key thing is to obviously keep the last stored text of the User, rather than overwriting it, simply displaying each input underneath each other, I have been advised Text is the best method for this.

**UPDATE**

Thanks to the comments and answer by Kevin, the user text is now showing in the gui, but when I enter something and click send again, it goes to the side, like this:

HeyHey

rather than :

Hey

Hey

My chatbot is linked to Dialogflow and so in between each user input the chatbot will respond.

Comment: With `state='disabled'`, the Text truly is disabled - programmatic changes are disallowed just as well as manual typing.  You have to momentarily enable it before inserting your text, then disable it again.

Comment: Thanks for replying, something like this still doesn't work, am I right in thinking that I'd need it put this in the `def Response()`  :
    `displayText.configure(state='normal')
    displayText.insert(window,result )
    displayText.configure(state='disabled')`

Comment: @jasonharper sorted now, up voted and thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as jasonharper indicated in the comments, you need to un-disable your text box before you can add text to it. Additionally, `displayText.insert(window,result)` is not the correct way to call it. `insert`'s first argument should be an index, not the window object.

Try:

```
def Response():
    #no need to use global here
    result = myText.get()
    displayText.configure(state='normal')
    displayText.insert(END, result)
    displayText.configure(state='disabled')
```

(You may need to do `tk.END` or `tkinter.END` instead of just `END`, depending on how you originally imported tkinter. It's hard to tell since you didn't provide that part of your code)

Comment: Thank you for the response @Kevin, that seems to have done the trick and have updated the question with the output,I was under the impression END dictated a possible new line?

Comment: I don't think so. If you want a newline, you can add it yourself: `displayText.insert(END, "\n" + result)`

Comment: Ignore that, think I solved the additional positioning with + '\n'
Thank you