# Access clipboard Windows (7) 64-bit

Tags: python, windows, 64-bit, clipboard

Is there a way to access (set, read etc.) the clipboard on Windows 7 64-bit in Python? I have seen PyWin32 but as far as I could see that was only 32-bit.

Answer (score 2):

Download the `amd64` version of `pywin32` for 64bit support, have a look at [`here`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/Build%20214/).

Answer (score 2):

There only is one clipboard that is shared between all programs, whether they are 32 or 64 bit. In other words you can just use the same clipboard code on 64 bit Windows as you do on 32 bit.

EDIT: I've just read İsmail's answer and I wonder if that is in fact what the OP is struggling with. My statement above is still true, but I may have misinterpreted the question.

Comment: OP might be just simply confused :) , but he shall know that pywin32 supports x64.

Answer (score 1):

The pyperclip.py module has cross-platform support for simple text copying/pasting.

http://coffeeghost.net/2010/10/09/pyperclip-a-cross-platform-clipboard-module-for-python/

Answer (score 0):

The easiest method I've seen is demonstrated in this post: [How do I copy a string to the clipboard on Windows using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/579687/how-do-i-copy-a-string-to-the-clipboard-on-windows-using-python/4203897#4203897)

It uses Tkinter, which is in the python standard library.