# PyQT - copy file to clipboard

Tags: python, pyqt

Is it possible to copy file to a clipboard?
As if it was pressed "ctrl+c". So that when I press "ctrl+v" in some folder, it will appear here.

http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qclipboard.html - cannot find anything about files.

```
file = 'C:\foo.file'
clipboard = QtGui.QApplication.clipboard()
????
```

Is it possible at all?

Comment: Are you copying and pasting within your application or do you need to copy the file to an external folder window?

Comment: External folder. As with text.

Comment: Remark: should be `QtGui.QGuiApplication`. (or `QtWidgets.QApplication`)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Clipboard data is modelled with `QMimeData` class, which can contain a list of URLs, including local filesystem URLs.

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

app = QtGui.QApplication([])

data = QtCore.QMimeData()
url = QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile('c:\\foo.file')
data.setUrls([url])

app.clipboard().setMimeData(data)
```

Comment: Remeber that the X11 clipboard needs the event loop running (`QApplication.exec_`).

Answer (score 5):

Create QUrls of the files, store them in a QMimeData and paste the QMimeData to the QClipboard. (Works for multiple files, tested on KDE 4, not sure if works on Windows.)

```
import sys

from PyQt4.QtCore import QMimeData, QUrl
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

# Create the urls.
url1 = QUrl('file1')
url2 = QUrl('file2')

# Create the mime data with the urls.
mime_data = QMimeData()
mime_data.setUrls([url1, url2])

# Copy the mime data to the clipboard.
clipboard = QApplication.clipboard()
clipboard.setMimeData(mime_data)

# Run the main loop.
# The X11 clipboard needs the event loop running.
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```