# Clipboard is not set after application exits?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, clipboard

With this example from [How do I copy a string to the clipboard on Windows using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/579687/how-do-i-copy-a-string-to-the-clipboard-on-windows-using-python) :

```
from tkinter import Tk
r = Tk()
r.withdraw()
r.clipboard_clear()
r.clipboard_append('i can has clipboardz?')
r.destroy()
```

The clipboard reverts to the old clipboard. Is there any way to avoid this? I'm using Ubuntu 13.04.

Answer (score 1):

No. The "clipboard" on X is not a discrete thing, but rather a notification that an application contains the piece of data that is seen as being "on" the clipboard. Other applications request this piece of data from that application, and the data is returned. This cannot work if the application that is supposed to respond with the data is no longer running.

Comment: This mostly makes sense, though if I copy some text from Geany, the text is kept in the clipboard after the application exits. How does this work?

Comment: It possibly launches another invisible (or iconified) process that waits for the clipboard contents to change ownership (get pasted), after which it exits. At least in the GTK bindings, you can listen for the ownership change event. Pretty standard technique.

Comment: @minerz029: Geany uses GTK+'s clipboard support instead of relying purely on X.

Comment: Your desktop environment provides a "clipboard manager", an always-running program that keeps a copy of the clipboard and makes it available to other programs.  Tkinter may not be interfacing with it properly: unlike Windows, X has multiple clipboards: the classic clipboard, the selection buffer, and application-private clipboards.  If Tkinter isn't using the classic clipboard, the manager may not be seeing the data.