# Is it possible to copy text to your clipboard and preserve it after closing my window?

Tags: python, tkinter, clipboard, copy-paste

I want to have a copy function in my program, but after it is copied, and the window is closed, my clipboard is wiped of all copied or cut text from my program.

Comment: Have a look at this answer - it seems like you will find a solution there:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46178950/tk-only-copies-to-clipboard-if-paste-is-used-before-program-exits

Answer (score 0):

[How do I copy a string to the clipboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/579687/how-do-i-copy-a-string-to-the-clipboard)

I think there you can find the answer

```
from Tkinter import Tk
r = Tk()
r.withdraw()
r.clipboard_clear()
r.clipboard_append('text')
r.update() # now it stays on the clipboard after the window is closed
```

Comment: I'm not having any luck. I'm trying to copy from an Entry widget and used a function that used entry.event_generate("<<Copy>>").
Now I am trying to use this in its function instead, but it just closes my window without adding anything to the clipboard.

Answer (score 0):

As of March 2023, on Kubuntu 20.04, I was not able to make it work with either Tkinter (as in a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73945220/11932107)), or [pyperclip](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42671266), or [pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36178407).

What finally did work for me was `xerox`:

> import xerox
>
> #produce the string you want to copy to the clipboard
> my_string = "here_is_a_nontrivial_string"
>
> #set the clipboard contents to the string
> xerox.copy(my_string)

After execution, the string "here_is_a_nontrivial_string" remained in the clipboard, and I was able to paste it into e.g. a text file, using ctrl+v.

Note that I had the same results regardless of whether I saved the code in a `.py` file and ran it using the command `python3`, or whether I saved it as a `bash` script (adding the line `#!/usr/bin/python3` at the top), making it executable, and invoking it as a command from the terminal.