# Python script importing results to ctrl-c memory

Tags: python, windows, memory, copy-paste, ctrl

I would like to know is it possible that python script would import results into clipboard (ctrl-C memory) on windows. This would enable me to manipulate-transfer results more easily.

Is it possible to do? How?

Comment: What do you mean by "ctrl-c memory"? Do you just mean the clipboard?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I copy a string to the clipboard on Windows using Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/579687/how-do-i-copy-a-string-to-the-clipboard-on-windows-using-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called the "clipboard"

Copied from [this link](http://coffeeghost.net/2010/10/09/pyperclip-a-cross-platform-clipboard-module-for-python/):

```
import ctypes
def winSetClipboard(text):
    GMEM_DDESHARE = 0x2000
    ctypes.windll.user32.OpenClipboard(0)
    ctypes.windll.user32.EmptyClipboard()
    try:
        # works on Python 2 (bytes() only takes one argument)
        hCd = ctypes.windll.kernel32.GlobalAlloc(GMEM_DDESHARE, len(bytes(text))+1)
    except TypeError:
        # works on Python 3 (bytes() requires an encoding)
        hCd = ctypes.windll.kernel32.GlobalAlloc(GMEM_DDESHARE, len(bytes(text, 'ascii'))+1)
    pchData = ctypes.windll.kernel32.GlobalLock(hCd)
    try:
        # works on Python 2 (bytes() only takes one argument)
        ctypes.cdll.msvcrt.strcpy(ctypes.c_char_p(pchData), bytes(text))
    except TypeError:
        # works on Python 3 (bytes() requires an encoding)
        ctypes.cdll.msvcrt.strcpy(ctypes.c_char_p(pchData), bytes(text, 'ascii'))
    ctypes.windll.kernel32.GlobalUnlock(hCd)
    ctypes.windll.user32.SetClipboardData(1,hCd)
    ctypes.windll.user32.CloseClipboard()
```