# I'm trying copy a string to the clipboard on Linux using Python3 and tkinter. But it's not working

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, tkinter, clipboard

I'm looking for some code to append a string to the clipboard and get the text from the clipboard ues Python3 and tkinter. And I find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/579687/how-do-i-copy-a-string-to-the-clipboard-on-windows-using-python). So I tried these codes:

```
from tkinter import Tk
r = Tk()
r.withdraw()
r.clipboard_clear()
r.clipboard_append('i can has clipboardz?')
r.destroy()
```

They're cleared my clipboard, but didn't append anything.


By the way, I tried `print(r.clipboard_get())`.

It's working out-of-the-box. But I can't append any text to the clipboard.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 It's working! but the text will lost after 10 seconds and the program must keep running. How to keep the text in clipboard and I don't need keep the program running?

Comment: From that answer: "If you do paste it within that time, it will remain in the clipboard even after the program ends." You'll have to keep the program running until you actually paste it. After you've pasted it once, it will remain in the clipboard even after you close the program.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Well, I'm sorry about I didn't see that. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score -1):

You can try using the clipboard library

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/clipboard/0.0.4

The gist of it is on that page

```
import clipboard
clipboard.copy("abc")  # now the clipboard content will be string "abc"
text = clipboard.paste()  # text will have the content of clipboard
```

Comment: I want to only use the tkinter without other module...