# Python tkinter clipboard.get() gives UnicodeDecodeErrors

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

With Python 3.4 on Windows 7, I use the following code to get text from the clipboard:

```
import tkinter

r = tkinter.Tk()
text = r.clipboard_get()
r.withdraw()
r.update()
r.destroy()
```

(This by the way reads the clipboard without showing any window).
The problem is, that this will sometimes produce "UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xed in position 0: invalid continuation byte".

For example when having this sign in the clipboard:

Is there a way to make tkinter ignore/replace those signs? I do not need them anyway, but other parts of the copied text.

Comment: You could try bypassing Tk entirely: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25678113/5987

Comment: @MarkRansom, How can those solutions know the encoding of random text copied into the clipboard?

Comment: Windows will *always* keep a copy of text in UTF-16 format as CF_UNICODE. If you copy non-Unicode text to the clipboard, it will be converted from the active code page to Unicode.