# can't invoke “event” command: application has been destroyed

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a simple code (test.py) to generate a popup window as shown below. It works fine when I run it directly in console.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.messagebox import showinfo

def popup():
    print("Hello World!")

root1 = tk.Tk()
b1 = tk.Button(root1, text="Print", command=popup)
b1.pack(fill='x')
root1.mainloop()
```

But when I call this code (test.py) from another py script by

```
exec(open('test.py').read())
```

It gives error message "can't invoke “event” command: application has been destroyed". I have checked the prior discussion on this topic, but it doesn't seem to help my case.

[can't invoke "event" command: application has been destroyed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45309090/cant-invoke-event-command-application-has-been-destroyed)

Can anybody please help? Thanks!

Comment: Instead of `exec(open('test.py').read())` use: `import test`. That is the proper way of running another python script from your main one

Comment: Thanks, I just tried to change to import test, it gave the same error.

Comment: Sorry but I'm unable to reproduce the problem. What python version are you using? What tkinter version are you using? What OS are you running? How did you install python?

Comment: Show us the code where you have used this, did you name both the windows same?

Comment: Thanks for the response! The main script is too long to show here. But I do have other GUI in the main script, and they are already destroyed before calling test.py. The names are `window.mainloop()`, `root.mainloop()`, so I use `root1.mainloop()` in test.py.