# Automatically copy Tkinter text widget content to clipboard?

Tags: python, tkinter, copy-paste

I have created a program in python using Tkinter that converts normal text, into some fancy text.

[image: screenshot]

I was wondering if it is possible for the output to be automatically copied to the clipboard once the 'Convert' button has been pushed.

Here is my code:

```
#Importing TKinter module
from tkinter import *

#Setting up the GUI window
win = Tk()
win.title("Font Converter")
win.resizable(0,0)

#Converting
def replace():
    text = entry.get("1.0",END)

    replacements = {

        #Upper case letters
        "A": "Ａ",
        "B": "Ｂ",
        "C": "Ｃ",
        "D": "Ｄ",
        "E": "Ｅ",
        "F": "Ｆ",
        "G": "Ｇ",
        "H": "Ｈ",
        "I": "Ｉ",
        "J": "Ｊ",
        "K": "Ｋ",
        "L": "Ｌ",
        "M": "Ｍ",
        "N": "Ｎ",
        "O": "Ｏ",
        "P": "Ｐ",
        "Q": "Ｑ",
        "R": "Ｒ",
        "S": "Ｓ",
        "T": "Ｔ",
        "U": "Ｕ",
        "V": "Ｖ",
        "W": "Ｗ",
        "X": "Ｘ",
        "Y": "Ｙ",
        "Z": "Ｚ",

        #Lower case letters
        "a": "ａ",
        "b": "ｂ",
        "c": "ｃ",
        "d": "ｄ",
        "e": "ｅ",
        "f": "ｆ",
        "g": "ｇ",
        "h": "ｈ",
        "i": "ｉ",
        "j": "ｊ",
        "k": "ｋ",
        "l": "ｌ",
        "m": "ｍ",
        "n": "ｎ",
        "o": "ｏ",
        "p": "ｐ",
        "q": "ｑ",
        "r": "ｒ",
        "s": "ｓ",
        "t": "ｔ",
        "u": "ｕ",
        "v": "ｖ",
        "w": "ｗ",
        "x": "ｘ",
        "y": "ｙ",
        "z": "ｚ",

        #Numbers
        "1": "１",
        "2": "２",
        "3": "３",
        "4": "４",
        "5": "５",
        "6": "６",
        "7": "７",
        "8": "８",
        "9": "９",
        "0": "０",

    }
    text = "".join([replacements.get(c, c) for c in text])
    output.delete('1.0', END)
    output.insert(END, str(text))

#Text Variables
enter = StringVar()

#Creating the widgets
l1 = Label(win, text="Enter text:")
entry = Text(win, width=50, height=3, wrap=WORD)
button = Button(win, text="Convert", width=20)
l2 = Label(win, text="Converted text:")
output = Text(win, width=50, height=3, wrap=WORD)

#Positioning the widgets
l1.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=5, sticky=W)
entry.grid(row=2, column=1, columnspan=2, padx=5, pady=(0,10))
button.grid(row=3, column=1, columnspan=2, pady=5)
l2.grid(row=4, column=1, padx=5, sticky=W)
output.grid(row=5, column=1, columnspan=2, padx=5, pady=(0,10))

#Button activation
button.configure(command=replace)

#So the program is on repeat
win.mainloop()
```

Please excuse the massive inefficiency, I'm still quite a noob when it comes to python.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This link can help you:

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/579687/how-do-i-copy-a-string-to-the-clipboard-on-windows-using-python)

```
from Tkinter import Tk
r = Tk()
r.withdraw()
r.clipboard_clear()
r.clipboard_append('i can has clipboardz?')
r.destroy()
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm not sure what the r.destroy() or in my case win.destroy() does, but it closes the window down. I removed that part and it works perfectly. Thanks again!

Comment: This was really helpful, you have no idea how hard it is to allow users to copy stuff into the clipboard manually on Mac with python 3

Answer (score 1):

Here's a little function that I used in one of my apps, which I attached to a tkinter button. You will need to change the "INFO_TO_COPY" comment to your actual data source.

```
def copy_button():
    clip = Tk()
    clip.withdraw()
    clip.clipboard_clear()
    clip.clipboard_append(INFO_TO_COPY)  // Change INFO_TO_COPY to the name of your data source
    clip.destroy()
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I'm away from any sort of documentation but if I recall correctly win.clipboard_append(output) should work for your case here