# How to store a string in my "copy & paste" to use it in other program

Tags: python, copy

I am writing a program to crawl links from the internet, and store it as a string. I would like to insert the string into an external program to run it. My idea is to do copy and pasting with keys control, how can I store string into my "copy & paste" area, or is there any good alternatives? Thanks!

Comment: save the string to a file, then read it back from that file in the external program if you can. or maybe a third-party module like [copypaste](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/copypaste)

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/579687/how-do-i-copy-a-string-to-the-clipboard-on-windows-using-python