# Copy highlighted text to clipboard, then use the clipboard to append it to a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyautogui

I'm trying to automate some actions in a browser or a  word processor with pyautogui module for Python 3 (Windows 10).

There is a highlighted text in a browser.

> `text`

the following script should print the highlighted text

```
import pyautogui as pya

# double clicks on a position of the cursor
pya.doubleClick(pya.position())

list = []
# a function copy_clipboard() should be called here
var = copy_clipboard()
list.append(var) 
print(list)
```

The output should be:

`[text]`

So how should the function `copy_clipboard()` look like?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: this sounds like something requests and beautifulsoup would be great at. Or at least selenium if you want to automate a browser

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I want that script to be working with text editors as well.

Comment: Is there something special it needs to do with the text editor?

Comment: Just copy a highlighted text (from a text editor/processor or a browser) and assign it to a variable in a script. If I did that manually it should've looked like Ctrl+C, Ctrl+V.

Comment: Look into using either the `Tkinter` or `ctypes` module. Here's the `ctypes` [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25678113/6221024) I've used in the past.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The keyboard combo <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> handles copying what is highlighted in most apps, and should work fine for you. This part is easy with `pyautogui`. For getting the clipboard contents programmatically, as others have mentioned, you could implement it using `ctypes`, `pywin32`, or other libraries. Here I've chosen `pyperclip`:

```
import pyautogui as pya
import pyperclip  # handy cross-platform clipboard text handler
import time

def copy_clipboard():
    pya.hotkey('ctrl', 'c')
    time.sleep(.01)  # ctrl-c is usually very fast but your program may execute faster
    return pyperclip.paste()

# double clicks on a position of the cursor
pya.doubleClick(pya.position())

list = []
var = copy_clipboard()
list.append(var) 
print(list)
```

Comment: That solution did work. And thank you for explaining why there should be a pause in the script - that was not obvious to me.

Answer (score 5):

Example using tkinter:

```
from tkinter import Tk
import pyautogui as pya

def copy_clipboard():
    root = Tk()     # Initialize tkinter
    root.withdraw() # hide the tkinter window
    pya.hotkey("ctrl", "c") # copy the text (simulating key strokes)
    clipboard = root.clipboard_get() # get the text from the clipboard
    return clipboard

copy_text = copy_clipboard()
print(copy_text)
```

[Tk().clipboard_get()](https://www.kite.com/python/docs/tkinter.Tk.clipboard_get) returns the current text in the clipboard.

Answer (score 4):

What soundstripe posted is valid, but doesn't take into account copying null values when there was a previous value copied.  I've included an additional line that clears the clipboard so null-valued copies remain null-valued:

```
import pyautogui as pya
import pyperclip  # handy cross-platform clipboard text handler
import time

def copy_clipboard():
    pyperclip.copy("") # <- This prevents last copy replacing current copy of null.
    pya.hotkey('ctrl', 'c')
    time.sleep(.01)  # ctrl-c is usually very fast but your program may execute faster
    return pyperclip.paste()

# double clicks on a position of the cursor
pya.doubleClick(pya.position())

list = []
var = copy_clipboard()
list.append(var) 
print(list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option to get highlighted/selected text:

```py
import subprocess
import shlex
selected_text = subprocess.check_output((shlex.split('xclip -out -selection')))
```

Answer (score -1):

You could import `pyperclip` and use `pyperclip.copy('my text I want copied')` and then use `pyperclip.paste()` to paste the text wherever you want it to go. You can find a reference [here](https://www.idiotinside.com/2017/06/07/copy-paste-text-to-clipboard-using-python/).

Comment: But we assume that the text is in another program maybe a browser or something like that. So how could you pass it as a parameter of `pyperclip.copy`?

Comment: @Muzol My apologies; I was unclear on what you wanted. I'm not sure there's a good way to do that. You might be better off using Ctrl + C