# Trouble Using tkinter, pandas to Copy List To Clipboard

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, tkinter, clipboard

Encountering trouble using tkinter to copy a list to Windows clipboard in Python 3. This code isn't throwing any errors, but its just not copying the list to the clipboard.

```
from tkinter import Tk
r = Tk()
r.withdraw()
r.clipboard_clear()
r.clipboard_append(mylist)
r.update()

print(mylist)
```

I tried using the pandas technique:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame(mylist.to_clipboard(excel=True, header=False, index=False)

print(mylist)
```

But with pandas its telling me that the `print(mylist)` syntax is wrong. And if I change things around it starts throwing an EOF error.

I already know pyperclip won't copy lists, which is unfortunate.

Pandas would be great due to the Excel feature, but I'm not sure if it's just for numbers? I'm trying to copy a list of strings (ie: "Joseph Jones Goes To Show 2342")

Thanks ahead of time.
- J

Comment: I think you will have better luck using `ctypes` in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/579687/how-do-i-copy-a-string-to-the-clipboard-on-windows-using-python). Might need to pre-format your list though.

Comment: are you trying to use Tkinter to copy a list from your program into the clipboard?

Comment: More info on ctypes approach appreciated. And Vasu, yes I am.