# How do you put the first word of a filename into your clipboard, ready for pasting; using python?

Tags: python, copy, rename, clipboard

I know you can do this with, pyautogui. But what would you use as an alternative?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I copy a string to the clipboard on Windows using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/579687/how-do-i-copy-a-string-to-the-clipboard-on-windows-using-python)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pyperclip](https://pypi.org/project/pyperclip/) to help you on that.

```
>>> import pyperclip
>>> import os
>>> pyperclip.copy(os.path.basename(DIR).split(" ")[0])
```

You can also paste it with `paste()`

NOTE: As said in the docs...

> Currently only handles plaintext.
>
> On Windows, no additional modules are needed.
>
> On Mac, this module makes use of the pbcopy and pbpaste commands,
>   which should come with the os.
>
> On Linux, this module makes use of the xclip or xsel commands, which
>   should come with the os. Otherwise run “sudo apt-get install xclip” or
>   “sudo apt-get install xsel” (Note: xsel does not always seem to work.)
>
> Otherwise on Linux, you will need the gtk or PyQt4 modules installed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pyperclip which is a cross platform module handle clipboard:

```
import os
import pyperclip

filepath = 'C:/mycode/code.py'
filename = os.path.basename(filepath)

# argument in split should enter the sep of two word, there is .
first_word = filename.split('.')[0]


pyperclip.copy(first_word)
```

If you don't want install a third party module, `os.system(f'echo {first_word} | clip')` maybe a easy method on Windows instead final statement.