# Copying a table into the clipboard

Tags: python-3.x, linux, windows, macos, clipboard

Suppose we have a Python structure representing a table (whichever, e.g. a list of lists).

Is there an elegant way to programmatically copy that structure into the clipboard, so that it can be correctly pasted as a table, e.g. in Microsoft Word or Excel? I am looking preferably for a portable solution, otherwise specific solutions for MacOS, Linux and Windows would be appreciated.

Comment: Just a guess, but on a Mac, I imagine you could start `pbcopy` in a subprocess and pipe your data to it...

Comment: See here https://github.com/georgefs/pyclip-copycat

Comment: Thanks a lot! The question is more focused on how you copy -- specifically -- a table into the clipboard, rather that any string.

Answer (score 1):

To copy a table in the form of a list of lists to the clipboard, first convert it to a string by concatenating values with tabs and rows with new lines:

```py
table = [
            list(range(10)),
            list(range(11, 21)),
            list(range(21, 31)),
]

result = '\n'.join(['\t'.join(map(str, row)) for row in table])

print(result)
```

This results in:

```
0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20
21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30
```

There are several ways to copy this to the clipboard. Here is a cross-platform method using `tkinter` based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4203897/9504155):

```py
from tkinter import Tk

r = Tk()
r.withdraw()
r.clipboard_clear()
r.clipboard_append(result)
r.update()
r.destroy()
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer! That's pretty straightforward.