# Python 3.x copy to clipboard without downloading aditional libraries?

Tags: python, clipboard

Is there a way to manage clipboard in python 3.x without the use of tkinter or other downloadable libraries ?
tkinter is a GUI library, it should have no business in clipboard or file management.
I purposely refuse to use tkinter for anything other then GUI.

Thank you.

```
import os
data = "hello world"
os.system("echo '%s' | pbcopy" % data)
```

the above does not work for windows

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I copy a string to the clipboard on Windows using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/579687/how-do-i-copy-a-string-to-the-clipboard-on-windows-using-python)

Comment: Not finding a 1 line of code solution without having to download libraries. Except tkinter but tkinter should not come near clipboard, its a GUI module, not a system module.
System module should do it or the OS module