# how to create copy and paste program with python

Tags: python

How do I write a program with Python that can act as a copy and paste in Windows? I made two buttons with the python library and want to do one copy in the windows environment and the other one in the paste. Thanks for helping me.

its my code

```
import tkinter as tk
import pyautogui as pg
import time


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("200x160")
root.resizable(False, False)


is_checked = tk.IntVar()


def alont():
    if is_checked.get() == 0:
        root.attributes('-topmost', False)   
    else:
        root.attributes('-topmost', True)

text1 = tk.Entry(root, font = ("area", 10), width = 5)

text1.config(insertwidth=1)

text1.place(x=10, y=137)

text1.insert(0, 1)
timer1 = text1.get()

def copy1():

    timer1 = text1.get()
    tm = int(timer1)
    time.sleep(tm)
    pg.hotkey('ctrl', 'c')

def paste1():

    timer1 = text1.get()
    tm = int(timer1)
    time.sleep(tm)
    pg.hotkey('ctrl', 'v')



btn1 = tk.Button(root, text="Copy", font=("area", 25), height = 1, width = 10)
btn1.config(command=copy1)
btn1.pack()

btn2 = tk.Button(root, text="Paste", font=("area", 25), height = 1, width = 10)
btn2.config(command=paste1)
btn2.pack()

chbutton = tk.Checkbutton(root, text="Always On Top", 
font=("area", 12), variable=is_checked)
chbutton.config(command=alont)
chbutton.place(x=60, y=133.5)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hi @mehran, can you please share your python code that has the buttons, we can direct you to some library options, but it will depend on the version of python you are using. For example: there is tkinter and gtk (https://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/button_widgets.html) that you can create widgets and guis - it all depends. It is easy to add this information and edit the question when you have time.

Comment: Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score -1):

There are existing libraries for this. See [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4203897/12332327) There's also [pyperclip.](https://pypi.org/project/pyperclip/)

Comment: pyperclip not working in text editors or file manager or else, not work in windows enviroment

Comment: @mehran jarnal It works in my environment. What issue are you having? There's also the solution offered in the other linked question through tkinter.

Comment: Is there a way to turn off my software focus? Never focus on my software. can i see your codes?? please