# How to add "copy id" button in matplot graph window

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, charts

I am working on product sell analysis project and for that i have created one donut chart for different products.Now my question is,how to add `copy id` button near the legends(or anywhere in the graph window) of doughnut chart so that user can copy product id directly from there

**Expected output**

[image]

**Code**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 3), subplot_kw=dict(aspect="equal"))

products = ["id 11111",
          "id 22222",
          "id 33333",
          "id 44444",
          "id 55555",
          "id 66666"]

data = [225, 90, 50, 60, 100, 5]

wedges, texts = ax.pie(data, wedgeprops=dict(width=0.5), startangle=-40)

bbox_props = dict(boxstyle="square,pad=0.3", fc="w", ec="k", lw=0.72)
kw = dict(arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="-"),
          bbox=bbox_props, zorder=0, va="center")

for i, p in enumerate(wedges):
    ang = (p.theta2 - p.theta1)/2. + p.theta1
    y = np.sin(np.deg2rad(ang))
    x = np.cos(np.deg2rad(ang))
    horizontalalignment = {-1: "right", 1: "left"}[int(np.sign(x))]
    connectionstyle = "angle,angleA=0,angleB={}".format(ang)
    kw["arrowprops"].update({"connectionstyle": connectionstyle})
    ax.annotate(products[i], xy=(x, y), xytext=(1.35*np.sign(x), 1.4*y),
                horizontalalignment=horizontalalignment, **kw)

ax.set_title("Matplotlib Products Sell: A donut")

plt.show()
```

**output**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The following code allows you to click on the annotation box and copies the content to the clipboard.

I use `pandas.io.clipboard` for doing so, as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59012099/1356000).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pandas.io.clipboard import copy


def onclick(event):
    copy(event.artist.get_text())


fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 3), subplot_kw=dict(aspect="equal"))
cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', onclick)

products = ["id 11111",
            "id 22222",
            "id 33333",
            "id 44444",
            "id 55555",
            "id 66666"]

annotations = []

data = [225, 90, 50, 60, 100, 5]

wedges, texts = ax.pie(data, wedgeprops=dict(width=0.5), startangle=-40)

bbox_props = dict(boxstyle="square,pad=0.3", fc="w", ec="k", lw=0.72)
kw = dict(arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="-"),
          bbox=bbox_props, zorder=0, va="center")

for i, p in enumerate(wedges):
    ang = (p.theta2 - p.theta1) / 2. + p.theta1
    y = np.sin(np.deg2rad(ang))
    x = np.cos(np.deg2rad(ang))
    horizontalalignment = {-1: "right", 1: "left"}[int(np.sign(x))]
    connectionstyle = "angle,angleA=0,angleB={}".format(ang)
    kw["arrowprops"].update({"connectionstyle": connectionstyle})
    ax.annotate(products[i], xy=(x, y), xytext=(1.35 * np.sign(x), 1.4 * y),
                horizontalalignment=horizontalalignment, picker=True, **kw)

ax.set_title("Matplotlib Products Sell: A donut")

plt.show()
```

Comment: Hey @Diziet Asahi thanks for your answer, i tried whatever you suggested but got this error `raise PyperclipException(EXCEPT_MSG)
pandas.io.clipboard.PyperclipException: 
    Pyperclip could not find a copy/paste mechanism for your system.`

Comment: I don't know your environment, so I cannot say which solution would work, but there are many solutions offered besides the answer I linked in that thread, so you might want to try a few until you find one that works for you

Comment: i think you haven't get my question i want to button `widget` over `matplot` graph window so that `onClick` it will copy the `product id`