# Why is PyAutoGUI replacing "<" with ">"?

Tags: python, pyautogui

Today I was writing a simple script using pyautogui and at some point I had to write the `<` sign, but pyautogui for some reason writes `>` instead of `<`. I tried using `write`, `typewrite` and `press` functions. It does not flip curly, normal and squared brackets, and the `>` sign.

Does anyone know why is this happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This usually happens due to the use of non-qwerty keyboards. When you use `write` (or `press`), pyautogui doesn't actually write that character, instead it looks for the associated key on your keyboard and presses it. As a part of this, it decides whether or not it needs to hold `Shift` while pressing this key to get the correct character written (for example to differentiate between `a` and `A`). As you can see in the code [here](https://github.com/asweigart/pyautogui/blob/5e4acb870f2e7ce0ea1927cc5188bc2f5ab7bbbc/pyautogui/__init__.py#L530-L536), the implementation of that is very minimalistic, and it even has a note saying that it will be different for non-qwerty keyboards. As you can see, both `<` and `>` return `True` when passed to that function.

So what I assume is that on your keyboard `<` and `>` are on the same key and you select between them by holding or not holding `Shift`. Pyuatogui will, however, press both with `Shift` (because the function return `True` for both), thus always writing the one that you get when you hold `Shift` and press the key.

You can either solve this by using a standart qwerty keyboard or by copying the `<` into your clipboard and then pasting it using `pyautogui.hotkey`. To copy a string to the clipboard see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/579687/how-do-i-copy-a-string-to-the-clipboard), or [pyperclip](https://pypi.org/project/pyperclip/).

Comment: Actually, I'm using an average qwerty keyboard, and both < and > keys are on different buttons, but anyways using pyperclip library worked, so thanks!