# os.system outputs too much?

Tags: python, system

I'm trying to do this, to get the content of the clipboard

```
clipboard_data = os.system("pbpaste")
```

But this doesn't work! Not only does it not store  whatever was in the clipboard (some text) in the var (returns 0) but it outputs the result of the command on the screen.

How can I make it work how I want?

Answer (score 4):

You should to look into what's offered in the [`subprocess` module](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) for Python.  In version 2.7 and later you can achieve what you want with the following, for example:

```
from subprocess import check_output
clipboard_data = check_output(["pbpaste"])
```

... or in earlier versions do:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
clipboard_data = Popen(["pbpaste"], stdout=PIPE).communicate()[0]
```

That's missing some error checking, but you get the idea...

Comment: I tried the code using Popen (I'm on Python 2.6) but I get an error telling me "PIPE" is not defined.

Comment: @The Dude With A Moustache: I had just updated the answer with an appropriate import statement :)

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of what you're trying to achieve (I'm not familiar with `pbpaste` and IMHO there are [better ways to access the clipboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101128/how-do-i-read-text-from-the-windows-clipboard-from-python)), `os.system` returns the exit status of the process it's invoking, not its standard output.

You should use `subprocess.Popen` (with its `communicate` method) to get the standard output.

Comment: Awesome thanks. I can't use win32clipboard, I'm developing on Mac. I tried @mark-longair's code using Popen (I'm on Python 2.6) but I get an error telling me "PIPE" is not defined.

Comment: I tried @mark-longair's code using Popen (I'm on Python 2.6) but I get an error telling me "PIPE" is not defined.

Comment: @The Dude With A Moustache: I updated that answer with the appropriate import to make that work

Answer (score -1):

A simple method is to use the

```
f = os.popen(command)
```

method, it returns a file like object and then you can use the method f.readline() to return a string. The method is quite simple though and shouldn't be used to process large amounts of data because it uses alot of the computers cpu power.