# Python - Clearing the user input?

Tags: python, input, echo

I'm pretty new to python, I'm using version 3.3.3.

Let's say we have this script:

```
name = "user"
say = input("Say: ")
print (name, "said:",say)
```

If I run it, the output will be:

```
Say: mytext
user said: mytext
```

I wanna know, is there a way to clear/delete the 'Say: mytext'?
Just to make it a little bit clearer:

```
I want:
    user said: hi
    user said: test
    user said: ..

I don't want:
    Say: hi
    user said: hi
    Say: test
    user said: test
```

That's all, thnx in advance:)

Comment: Replace `say = input("Say: ")` with `say = input()`

Comment: This is not possible. See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7174401/2297365).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot simply tell the `input` function to hide the user input. But you can use the `getpass` function which will work all the same:

```
from getpass import getpass

name = "user"
say = getpass(prompt="")
print (name, "said:",say)
```

Just remember to set the `prompt` parameter to the value you want (empty string in this case), otherwise `Password:\n` will be displayed.

Answer (score 1):

```
name = "user"
say = input("Say: ")
sys.stdout.write("\033[F")
print (name, "said:", say)
```

Code on 3rd line moves cursor up one line.