# Input and Print

Tags: python, string, variables

I am trying to get a input to be typed after the "Choice: " but i also want to continue "*" around the whole text... Im  not sure how to do it even after trying multiple times with variations and research i couldn't dind an answer...

```
print("  ********School Quizes********  ")
print("  *                           *  ")
print("  *       A) Register         *  ")
print("  *       B) Loging           *  ")
print("  *       C) Quit             *  ")
print("  *                           *  ")
input("  *                Choice: ") & print(" *  ")
```

so that it is printed with "Choice:(here will be the input) * "

Comment: why is having an asterisk afterwards to important?

Comment: it part of a larger code which i have been asked to do because this sort of thing can be interpreted to be used in my school work too,,,

Comment: `input("  *                Choice: ") & print(" *  ")` what's this? bitwise and on 2 functions?

Comment: whats your os ?

Comment: [Format Specification Mini Language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Possible to get user input without inserting a new line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7173850/possible-to-get-user-input-without-inserting-a-new-line)

Comment: @MohammadAthar: no this is not!! this is a nice question, he wants a customize terminal input box!

Comment: not sure mate i was just trying out a few things that work in other languages

Comment: @Alzz_HD: you asked a nice question! unfortunately, Some people do not understand!!!!

Comment: it's okay, btw im using windows 10 with a python idle

Answer (score 1):

Technically, you could just do this:

```
print("  ********School Quizes********  ")
print("  *                           *  ")
print("  *       A) Register         *  ")
print("  *       B) Loging           *  ")
print("  *       C) Quit             *  ")
print("  *                           *  ")
input("  *       Choice:             *  ")
```

All the text in the quotation marks do is that it just acts as text to be prompted, which is why this works.

Comment: even if i do this when inputing it will be like so, " *       Choice:             * (input will go here)  " but i want it like this "*       Choice:(input here)             * "

Answer (score 0):

I can do it this way. But I feel this is really a hack...

```
x = input('''
  ********School Quizes********  
  *                           *  
  *       A) Register         *  
  *       B) Loging           *  
  *       C) Quit             *  
  *                           *  
                              *\r  *             Choice:    ''')
```

Comment: this has not worked at all... in fact please test codes before hand next time, im always thankful for the support and help though!

Comment: i did test it using the python interpreter of jupyter notebook's terminal. that's a unix environment.