# function choose_website syntax error (Basics)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to write a function to choose a website over several saved URLs.
My function looks like this:

```
website = ''
def choose_website(website_name):
  nfl = 'https://www.nfl.com'
  nba = 'http://www.nba.com'
  fifa = 'http://www.fifa.com'
  If website_name = "nfl":
      website = nfl
  elif website_name = "nba":
      website = nba
  elif website_name = "fifa":
      website = fifa
  else:
      print 'Invalid website, please try again'
choose_website(raw_input("Please insert website(nfl/nba/fifa): ")
```

In short, I store the websites URLS in their names, and I ask the user to enter the names and this will store the desired website URL in the "website" variable.
However when I try to run this, I received a syntax error:

```
  If website_name = "nfl":
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I have no idea why it does that, can anyone help me?
I'm using Python 3.4

Comment: python is case sensitive. Change `If` to `if`.

Comment: Capital I? Assignment (single equals) instead of equality comparison (double equals)?

Comment: The Capital I was only here in the post (accident, sorryyy) But the double equals solved it! thank you :D

Comment: Change '=' to '==' for equality comparison.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Possible to get user input without inserting a new line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7173850/possible-to-get-user-input-without-inserting-a-new-line)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As people say `python is case sensitive. Change If to if`
and replace `=` to double `==`
more details in the [value-comparisons](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#value-comparisons)

```
  if website_name == "nfl":
  #^^             ^^
      website = nfl
  elif website_name == "nba":
  #                 ^^
      website = nba
  elif website_name == "fifa":
  #                 ^^
      website = fifa
```

and please read the [pep-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)