# How to print the input string as a float (1 into 1.0) python

Tags: python

Working on a program for class. I have the following code, however, even though the code works fine; I have a formatting issue.

This here is the correct output that I am trying to get

[image]

This is what I currently have; and is wrong

[image]

Below is the current code I have:

```
num_rods = input ( "Input rods: You input " )
num_rods = float ( num_rods )
print ("rods.")
```

What is the error here? and how can I make my code look like the example; thanks.

Comment: You don't print your variable. You just print the string `"rods."`

Comment: I don't think that first image actually shows the entered value because you're required to press enter, which makes a line break. According to what do you need to use `input()` function?

Comment: Also, you're already printing `1.0 rods` at the end, so the title of the question is misleading

Comment: The first one if the "right answer", the next one is what I personally got

Comment: I think we all understand that... But the "code you currently have" never prints "Conversions", so what's in the question is not a [mcve]

Comment: Haven't you found this in your research? https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#format-string-syntax It's hard to believe ... or this: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
print('{} rods.'.format(num_rods))
```

or

```
print('rods: ',num_rods)
```

Also, be careful with statements of this type. Check what happens to the code if, instead of inputting an int or float, you pass the character 'a' for example.

Comment: This won't print `1.0`  if just `"1"` is given

Comment: That's the right answer (the first one) THANK YOU VERY MUCH; I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You're seeing a line break, which cannot be avoided

[Possible to get user input without inserting a new line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7173850/possible-to-get-user-input-without-inserting-a-new-line)

But you can work around it

```
entered = input ( "Input rods: You input " )  # literally type "1.0 rods."
amount, _ = entered.split()
... 
print ("Minutes to walk {:.1f} rods:".format(amount))  # but you're already printing this
```