# deleting line space after input()

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, input

How to delete an empty line after using `input()` in python.

```
annual_salary =  int(input("Enter your annual salary:"))
portion_saved = float(input("Enter the percent of your salary to save, as a decimal:"))
```

Comment: What do you mean by *delete an empty line*?

Comment: When it is asking input after giving input am getting a blank line. You can run the code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Possible to get user input without inserting a new line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7173850/possible-to-get-user-input-without-inserting-a-new-line)

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure what you are asking, the code seems to work fine without an empty line:

[image: output]

Read up the documentation about `input()`:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input

> **input(*[prompt]*)**
>
> If the prompt argument is present, it is written to standard output without a trailing newline.

So if you do not want an empty line, make sure to add in a prompt.

See 
[Possible to get user input without inserting a new line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7173850/possible-to-get-user-input-without-inserting-a-new-line) if your issue is the newline after people inserted a value.