# I want to print and input in the same line in python. How can I do it?

Tags: python, input, printing, coordinates

I want to print and input in the same line in python. But I don't need a print then multi input. 
Example : I want to see them on the command screen:

`Coordinates : X = 52 "<ENTER>" Y = 964 "<ENTER>" Z = 651`

Enter key will be pressed after entering each coordinate. will request the next coordinate on the same line.

Actually, I want the following operations to be done in one line.

`print('Coordinates  : X') = input() , print('Y') input(), print('Z') input()`

i tried it. But i don't want it. I need, firstly print('Coordinates X :') then input to a variable. print('Y :') then input to other variable. print('Z:') then input to another varible. but all this commands must be same line.

[image]

Thank you, Best Regards!

Comment: Try `print(your_string, end="")` or `print(your_string, end=" ")` if you want a space after your string.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like

```
print("Coordinates:  X = {0}, Y = {1}, Z = {2}".format(input(), input(), input()))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried it and I have added a pic of the command. I have explained again. Regards!!

Comment: How about something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/47944991/8885087