# How can i delete input question in console?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to overwrite the input with a new output. I want to do the same thing (https://stackoverflow.com/a/8436827/14079038) but I need to overwrite the input.

My code returns:

```
while not addIp.__eq__(''):
    ignoredIp.append(addIp)
    print(addIp)
    addIp = input('Would you like to add ip ? (None = no): ')
```

```
Would you like to add ip ? (None = no): 1.1.1.1
1.1.1.1
Would you like to add ip ? (None = no): 1.1.1.2
1.1.1.2
Would you like to add ip ? (None = no):
```

But i want something like this:

```
10.11.100.66
10.11.100.67
10.11.100.68
10.11.100.69
10.11.100.70
Would you like to add ip ? (None = no):
```

Comment: why `while not addIp.__eq__(''):` ? why not normal `while not addIp == '':` or shorter `while not addIp:`

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do.

Comment: if you write in the same line then use `end='\r'` in `print`. But it will not work with `input()` which sends `\n` to console/terminal and you can't stop it. Maybe if you will use modules like [curses](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/curses.html)` which can use special codes in some consoles/terminals  to move cursor in any place then you could move back to previous line.

Comment: You want the output on the screen to show the IP addresses only, without the questions. Is that what you want? @furas gave you the answer.

Comment: I want to modify delete the writing of the input to the console

Comment: Yes it's this @Tarik

Comment: See @furas answer.

Comment: @furas Post your answer for upvote.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41459565/2988730. Coupled with '\r', you're all set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you write in the same line then use `end='\r'` in `print()` and it will not move to next line.

But it will not work with `input()` which sends `\n` to console/terminal and you can't stop it. Maybe if you will use modules like [curses](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/curses.html) which can use special codes in some consoles/terminals to move cursor in any place then you could move back to previous line.

---

On Linux terminal you can use code `\033[nA` to move `n` lines up.

This way you can use `\033[1A` to move to previous line and print text in place of question.

It needs also some spaces at the end to remove text from longer question.

```
addIp = '?'
while addIp:
    addIp = input('Would you like to add ip ? (None = no): ')
    print('\033[1A' + addIp + ' '*40)
```

See [other codes](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/the-linux-command/9781593273897/ch13s04.html). Linux uses similar codes to colorize text.

---

There are also modules which should work with Windows, Linux,

- [curses](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/curses.html)
- [npyscreen](http://www.npcole.com/npyscreen/)
- [urwid](http://urwid.org/)

and they are used to draw widgets in text mode (`TUI` - Text User Interface)

---

Not all consoles/terminals can respect these codes - often consoles in IDEs/editors don't respect these code.

Comment: Excellent simple solution.  Something new has been learned, thanks!

Comment: I use a windows system and when I write `import curses` it's make me error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_curses'`

Comment: @SimonBarras I don't use Windows to test it but `curses` as standard module should work on all systems. But I found also external module [windows-curses](https://pypi.org/project/windows-curses/) and maybe it will works for your. This link has also link to [curses](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#curses) on page very useful for Windows users - [Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs)