# How can I fix sublime text input?

Tags: python, python-3.x, input

so if I do something like this:

`name = input("Enter your name: ")`

then when I put in a name like bob for example it will just go to the next line.
How do I fix this?

Comment: what do you want it to do ?

Comment: Seems like duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7173850/possible-to-get-user-input-without-inserting-a-new-line/7175665
`input` always goes to new line, sublime text or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to do something similar the other day. If you run your code from the command prompt instead of within sublime it should correctly place the input in the variable and continue with the program.