# python 3 input without newline

Tags: python, input

I am new to coding. And I would like to know if there's a way for input function to not print newline character after the value is entered. Something like print function's argument end. Is there any way?

Comment: Can you please give more information about your example?

Comment: Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7173850/possible-to-get-user-input-without-inserting-a-new-line). But the answer for the most part is no.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can't make input() trigger by anything besides 'Enter' hit (other way may be using sys.stdin and retrieving character one-by-one until you receive some stop marker, but it's difficult both for programmer and for user, I suppose). As a workaround I can the suggest the following: if you can know the length of line written before + length of user input, then you can use some system codes to move cursor back to the end of previous line, discarding the printed newline:

```
print("This is first line.")
prompt = "Enter second: "
ans = input(prompt)
print(f"\033[A\033[{len(prompt)+len(ans)}C And the third.")
```

`\033[A` moves cursor one line up and `\033[<N>C` moves cursor N symbols right. The example code produces the following output:

```
This is first line.
Enter second: USER INPUT HERE And the third.
```

Also note that the newline character is not printed by your program, it's entered by user.

Comment: Thanks a lot this will help me.

Comment: **this should be marked as solved**.

Answer (score -1):

name=input('Enter your name : ')
print('hello',name,end='')
I know about the end function which is abov

Comment: OP is asking if there's a way to get around the newline at the end of the `input()`