# Creating while loop for multiple functions call

Tags: python, function

To put it simply, I'm currently learning to make function call. I want to level it up a bit by making simple main menu selection for desired function, while accepting user input.

But the problem is, the code is stuck without returning anything. I can input value for x and y but then the code stops processing the math equations.

```
print ("Select function : ")
print ("1. Addition")
print ("2. Substraction")
print ("3. Multiplication")
print ("4. Exit")
print ("")
z = input("Input your selection here : ")
x = int(input("Enter x value : "))
y = int(input("Enter y value : "))

def add(x,y):
  return x + y

def min(x,y):
  return x - y

def mult(x,y):
  return x * y

loop = True

while loop:
  if z == '1':
    add(x,y)
  elif z == '2':
    min(x,y)
  elif z == '3':
    mult(x,y)
  elif z == '4':
    loop = False
```

Any advice to make it work? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few issues in your code:

- You have to put your `print` statements inside the `while` loop inorder to show the menu to the user until the user exits.
- `min()` is a reserved function in Python - *It returns the minimum value of all the values passed to it*. **Don't Use it. Use some other name instead.**
- The reason you are not getting anything in output is *you are not printing the return results of functions.* Use `print` for all function calls inside your `while` loop [like this `print(add(x,y))` ].

Code with all the above changes:

```
def add(x,y):
  return x + y

def diff(x,y):
  return x - y

def mult(x,y):
  return x * y

loop = True

while loop:
    print ("Select function : ")
    print ("1. Addition")
    print ("2. Substraction")
    print ("3. Multiplication")
    print ("4. Exit")
    print ("")
    z = input("Input your selection here : ")
    if z == '4':
        break
    else:
        x = int(input("Enter x value : "))
        y = int(input("Enter y value : "))
        if z == '1':
            print(add(x,y))
        elif z == '2':
            print(diff(x,y))
        elif z == '3':
            print(mult(x,y))
```

Comment: Thank you for the concise and insightful answer! It's interesting to see nested loop in use here. I'm still trying to understand the concept.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few issues.

1. you are taking the input outside the loop, then you are entering into the loop. That way, `loop` won't be False anytime. The loop will go forever.
2. you are returning the value but not printing it. use `print(...)`
3. `min` is a built-in function. So don't define a new function called `min`

```
print ("Select function : ")
print ("1. Addition")
print ("2. Substraction")
print ("3. Multiplication")
print ("4. Exit")
print ("")


def add(x,y):
  return x + y

def minus(x,y):
  return x - y

def mult(x,y):
  return x * y


while True:
  z = input("Input your selection here : ")
  x = int(input("Enter x value : "))
  y = int(input("Enter y value : "))
  if z == '1':
    print(add(x,y))
  elif z == '2':
    print(minus(x,y))
  elif z == '3':
    print(mult(x,y))
  elif z == '4':
    break
```

Answer (score 0):

The value of `z` and `loop` is the same throughout the loop so, it's looping infintely.
You can try this:

```
print ("Select function : ")
print ("1. Addition")
print ("2. Substraction")
print ("3. Multiplication")
print ("4. Exit")
print ("")


def add(x,y):
  return x + y

def subs(x,y):
  return x - y

def mult(x,y):
  return x * y



while True:
    z = input("Input your selection here : ")
    if z == '4':
        break
    x = int(input("Enter x value : "))
    y = int(input("Enter y value : "))
    if z == '1':
        print(add(x,y))
    elif z == '2':
        print(subs(x,y))
    elif z == '3':
        print(mult(x,y))
```

You can you `break` as it's easier.
You can add `z==4` at front so you don't need to input other values.
`print` to display values.

Answer (score 0):

Not so bad for the first shot) The [@Ram](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2773206/ram) corrected the mistakes. But the real question is why the python input function doesn't have a filter option.

I've heard a lot of pain in [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7173850/possible-to-get-user-input-without-inserting-a-new-line)

Perhaps if you don't want to get infinite scrolling of console. You could use the [console module](https://pypi.org/project/console/). It will available after executing `pip install console` in the terminal.

```
from sys import stdout
from console.utils import wait_key, clear_line, sc
from console.detection import get_position

print ("Select function : ")
print ("1. Addition")
print ("2. Substraction")
print ("3. Multiplication")
print ("4. Exit")
print ("")

def _input(prompt, result):
  if result is not None:
    cursor_pos = get_position()
    with sc.location(y = cursor_pos[1] - 1):
      clear_line()
      stdout.write('\r>>Last command result is %s' % result)
  clear_line()
  stdout.write('\r' + prompt)
  data = ''
  key = wait_key()
  while key != '\r':
    data += key
    stdout.write(key)
    stdout.flush()
    key = wait_key()
  return data

def add(x,y):
  return x + y

def diff(x,y):
  return x - y

def mult(x,y):
  return x * y

r = None

while True:
    z = _input("Input your selection here : ", r)
    if z == '4':
        break
    else:
        x = int(_input("Enter x value : ", r))
        y = int(_input("Enter y value : ", r))
        if z == '1':
            r = add(x,y)
        elif z == '2':
            r = diff(x,y)
        elif z == '3':
            r = mult(x,y)

print()
```

Comment: Thank you! This is a lot to take in for a beginner, but this technique seems applicable in the long run