# Python input without newline

Tags: python

I have my code:

```
a= int(input("Enter a number: "))
print("Your number: %d" %a)
```

My output will be:

```
Enter a number: 4
Your number: 4
```

Does any way that I can do my output in 1 line? I expected my output wil be `Enter a number: 4 You number: 4`  without newline

Comment: It is not possible with `input()`

Comment: @PCM can you give me another way to do it? WIthout input is ok

Comment: Already ansewered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7173850/possible-to-get-user-input-without-inserting-a-new-line

Comment: @FranArenas, link is python2 and the question is in python3

Comment: @PCM That doesn't mean that the solutions wont work. Most stuff actually works both in python2 & python3.

Comment: Yeah, but `curses` doesn't work for python3 does it? But `msvcrt` works.