# How to get value of input within same print call?

Tags: python

Example of what I want/have:

```py
print(input('> Discord Webhook: '), f'{"None" if len(input) < 1 else input}')
```

I want it to print `None` if the input value is less than 1, or else just print the output normally.

Comment: I don't think you can do that because `input` is a built-in function that is called everytime it is in the code. You can just do `webhook = input('> Discord Webhook: ')` and then do anything with the string as you like.

Comment: @Minh-LongLuu I have tried printing it with `end=""` after the input but it still prints on new line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change what shows up in terminal where `input` was given, you can use ANSI escape codes to control the cursor directly. This way you can edit specific parts of the terminal output after they have already been printed.

```
prompt = '> Discord Webhook: '
webhook = input(prompt)
if not webhook:
    print('\u001b[1A', end = "") # Move cursor one line up
    print(f'\u001b[{len(prompt)}C', end = "") # Move cursor past prompt
    print('\u001b[0K', end = "") # Clear rest of line
    print("None")
```

On Windows you might need to do the following for cmd to recognise ANSI codes properly:

```
import os
os.system("")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want just to print `None` in place of an empty string you can do that with a simple `or`:

```
print(input('> Discord Webhook: ') or None)
```

Note that this does not actually capture the input for you to use on a later line.  Usually when you call `input()` you want to assign its result to a variable:

```
webhook = input('> Discord Webhook: ') or None
print(webhook)
# do whatever else you're going to do with that value
```

Comment: The input will still be shown in the console though :/ Showing it twice doesn't make sense.

Comment: It doesn't, but that's what OP asked how to do... ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: I am the OP and I want the output on the same line as the input to make sense for the user.

Comment: That wasn't mentioned in the question at all.  Sounds like what you're really after is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7173850/possible-to-get-user-input-without-inserting-a-new-line

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish this by making it appear like the input was changed to none using the `clear` command and printing the input text with "None" after it.

```py
import os
webhook = input('> Discord Webhook: ')
if len(webhook) < 1:
  os.system('clear')
  print('> Discord Webhook: None')
```

Comment: You might want to check out [ANSI escape codes](https://www.lihaoyi.com/post/BuildyourownCommandLinewithANSIescapecodes.html#deletion) for less drastic solution than clearing the entire console.

Comment: @matszwecja I don't really understand those or how to use them.

Comment: Check my answer for an example.