# Clear Clipboard?

Tags: python, clipboard

Is it possible for python to clear the clipboard? If so ... how can I do it?

I need this so in my quiz program, students can't copy paste answers from the internet and other files.

**EDIT:** Im using WinXP and Python 2.6

Comment: ¬¬ The will still be able to write them down, don't they?

Comment: similar question, same basic answer: [How do I read text from the (windows) clipboard from python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/101128/how-do-i-read-text-from-the-windows-clipboard-from-python)

Comment: @OscarRyz they can type in their answers

Comment: @kmote hi, im having this error when importing win32clipboard. ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.... have any idea? already download pywin32 from here http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/Build216/pywin32-216.win32-py2.6.exe/download

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
from ctypes import windll
if windll.user32.OpenClipboard(None):
    windll.user32.EmptyClipboard()
    windll.user32.CloseClipboard()
```

No external libraries needed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can for that you have to use [`PyWin32`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/) module which is a python module for windows ectension.

Take a look at its [EmptyClipboard](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.5/pywin32/win32clipboard__EmptyClipboard_meth.html)  method.

> The EmptyClipboard function empties the clipboard and frees handles to
>   data in the clipboard. The function then assigns ownership of the
>   clipboard to the window that currently has the clipboard open.

Comment: Hi i download pyWin32. how do i import it please? im having error when using import win32clipboard, win32con, random. im getting this ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

Comment: @Katherina: which version of PyWin32you downloaded.Download the one corresponding to Python2.6

Comment: yes i did download the installer for python 2.6. idk why it game me that error on import. anyway ill try to find it out again.