# clipboard access

Tags: python, windows

I am trying to retrieve texts from the clipboard using Python module called win32clipboard, as it is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101128/how-do-i-read-text-from-the-windows-clipboard-from-python?answertab=active#tab-top).
But Windows 7 does not allow to access the clipboard with the error `1418 - ERROR_CLIPBOARD_NOT_OPEN` as I use:

```
data = win32clipboard.GetClipboardData()
```

How can I defeat the system and get the data?

Comment: Did you open clipboard first? Use `OpenClipboard()`

Comment: Yes, with 'win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()'

Comment: What do you receive from 'OpenClipboard' function? If zero then call `GetLastError` and see what happened.

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#6>", line 1, in <module>
    data = win32clipboard.GetClipboardData()
pywintypes.error: (1418, 'GetClipboardData', 'Буфер обмена для потока команд не открыт.')`; 'Буфер обмена для потока команд не открыт.' is "Clipboard is not open for instruction stream" in Russian

Comment: run it as administrator.

Comment: As a matter of fact, the account I use is the administrator account. I am trying to run the code in the standart IDLE, just to see what will happen.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have not opened the clipboard twice. You must close it then reopen it.

The open-close operations can't be nested.