# How can I copy from an html file to the clipboard in Python in formatted text?

Tags: python, html, windows, clipboard, richtext

I'm writting a Word document and I'd like to paste a formatted code-snippets directly from clipboard.

At this moment I am able to write these snippets into an .html file to the harddisk. My goal is to extend my Python script and load this .html file on the clipboard in "formatted text" to directly paste at Word.

Does anyone knows any way to do this in Python?

Thanks in advance.

Sherab

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I've found a solution for this.

http://code.activestate.com/recipes/474121-getting-html-from-the-windows-clipboard/

It's work pretty well... if anyone wants more information about the clipboard just take a look here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649013(v=vs.85).aspx

Download the pywin32 module and with win32clipboard you can do everything.

Answer (score 1):

Nobody mentioned yet [klembord](https://github.com/OzymandiasTheGreat/klembord). It works on Linux and Windows, and supports [HTML clipboard format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dataxchg/html-clipboard-format).

#### Installation

```
pip install klembord
```

#### Usage

```py
import klembord
klembord.init()

# Case 1
klembord.set_with_rich_text('', 'Normal text, <i>Italic text</i>, <b>Bold text</b>, Normal text')

# Case 2
klembord.set_with_rich_text('', 'This is a <a href="https://github.com/OzymandiasTheGreat/klembord">link</a>')
```

#### Short explanation

The `set_with_rich_text` takes two arguments. The first argument is the plain text alternative, which is used if you paste the content somewhere that does not support rich text formatting (such as Notepad). The second argument is the html formatted clipboard, which supports for example `<a>`, `<i>` and `<b>` HTML tags.

#### Example output

When pasted to a rich text editor, the output from the example above would look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I used com interface to do it.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model

The simpliest way:
- create word template in microsoft word.
- paste text from code in your template.

Comment: I am trying to load a code.html file from disk and having it on the clipboard to paste it on the Microsoft Word in rich format...