# Send pygments-highlighted code to Windows clipboard

Tags: python, windows, clipboard, pygments

I am looking for answers that may present alternative methods / modifications related to:

- My method of sending data to the clipboard
- The choice of Lexer

That may solve the following issue...

I aim to be able to send raw `python` via some process to my clipboard such that I can paste it directly into a Microsoft application (such as Outlook) as formatted text as below

[image]

I can only achieve the following raw `pygments` output. `RtfFormatter` shown but same occurs with `HtmlFormatter`

[image]

## Copy to Clipboard Method

I use the `copy` func from the post https://stackoverflow.com/a/27291478/4013571
 as

```
import ctypes

def copy(text):
    """Copies a string, ``text``, to Windows Clipboard (https://stackoverflow.com/a/27291478/4013571)"""
    GMEM_DDESHARE = 0x2000
    CF_UNICODETEXT = 13
    d = ctypes.windll   # cdll expects 4 more bytes in user32.OpenClipboard(None)
    try:  # Python 2
        if not isinstance(text, unicode):
            text = text.decode('mbcs')
    except NameError:
        if not isinstance(text, str):
            text = text.decode('mbcs')
    d.user32.OpenClipboard(0)
    d.user32.EmptyClipboard()
    hCd = d.kernel32.GlobalAlloc(GMEM_DDESHARE, len(text.encode('utf-16-le')) + 2)
    pchData = d.kernel32.GlobalLock(hCd)
    ctypes.cdll.msvcrt.wcscpy(ctypes.c_wchar_p(pchData), text)
    d.kernel32.GlobalUnlock(hCd)
    d.user32.SetClipboardData(CF_UNICODETEXT, hCd)
    d.user32.CloseClipboard()
```

I have also tried [`pyperclip.copy`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyperclip) with no success

## Syntax Highlighting Method

```
from pygments import highlight
from pygments.lexers import PythonLexer
from pygments.formatters import RtfFormatter  # Same occurs using HtmlFormatter

raw_python = '''
def merge_two_dicts(x, y):
    """Given two dicts, merge them into a new dict as a shallow copy."""
    z = x.copy()
    z.update(y)
    return z
'''

highlighted = highlight(raw_python, PythonLexer(), RtfFormatter())
copy(highlighted)
```

Comment: tried: https://gist.github.com/Erreinion/6691093 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/17298897/4013571

Comment: some info but not too helpful https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649015(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: tried but gives clipboard error: https://github.com/lucasmazza/copy-as-rtf/blob/master/lib/winclipcopy.py

Comment: Go HTML (it works for Outlook, Thunderbird, Open Office etc), but use inline styles `<p style="color:#0f0;">...</p>`. Link form your first comment looks promissing.