# How to read tabular data copied from Excel into clipboard using python?

Tags: python, excel, clipboard, tabular

Is it possible to fetch the tabular data copied from Excel into a list, tuple or dictionary using python?
The data will contain multiple rows and columns, such as range `A1:B10`, therefore the python array should contain row and column index information as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you to save the file as csv and use `numpy.genfromtxt`

For instance

```
import numpy as np
data = np.genfromtxt("G:/mydata.csv", delimiter=',', dtype=object)
```

Choose your params accordingly. From an array you can easily convert to anything you like. If you know, that you have doubles all over, you can set `dtype=np.float` forthwith.

Comment: I just copy a range from an Excel table. Can python access this tabular data in the clipboard?

Comment: @alwbtc Didn't read your question carefully. Check out [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/101128/how-do-i-read-text-from-the-windows-clipboard-from-python)

Answer (score 0):

There are some libraries can help you read data from Excel files in Python.

- [Library for developers to extract data from Microsoft Excel (tm)
  spreadsheet files](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd) for Excel 2003-
- [openpyxl - A Python library to
  read/write Excel 2007 xlsx/xlsm files](http://pythonhosted.org/openpyxl/) for Excel 2007+

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to read a file. I just want to get the clipboard data into a python array.