# Python: Extract Formatted Text from Word

Tags: python, text, clipboard, docx

Using the docx module, I was able to put formatted(bulleted) text in a Word document.

However, I want this formatted text to go into my clipboard so I can instantly paste it into a main document.

What commands should I use to put this formatted text in my clipboard for pasting in another Word document?

This is how I was able to create and format the text:

```
    para=doc.add_paragraph()
    run = para.add_run(text)
    font = run.font
    font.name = 'Calibri'
    font.size = docx.shared.Pt(9)
    para.style = doc.styles['List Bullet']
```

Comment: Check this question out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/101128/how-do-i-read-text-from-the-windows-clipboard-from-python. Copy an example of the type of list you want to copy then check what formatted text looks like in the clipboard. At that point you can use pywin32 or another module such as `pyperclip` or `xerox` to copy the list into the clipboard.