# python selenium code to save text in a variable from clipboard which is copied to the clipboard by click of an element

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

On my webpage I have a window as shown in the image below. It has a division which shows the password. When I click on the "copy" element, it copies the password onto the clipboard. However this window closes within 30 seconds and then the copied password on the clipboard will be lost.

[image]

My intention is to save this password, copied on clipboard, into a variable to be used in later part of my python selenium  code.

I'm able to successfully click this "copy" element via the automated selenium script which then copies the password to clipboard. This is my code:

```
    ''' I will change time.sleep() later to appropriate WebdriverWait. This is just for test. '''
    ''' This also means that I will have to save the copied password from clipboard within 10seconds, '''
    ''' before the window closes '''
    time.sleep(20)
    copy_button = self.chrome_driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="button__container__not-show-spinner"]/div[@class="button__text"]')
    copy_button.click()
```

I read an article closest to my query here, which talks about importing `tkinter` module: [Accessing text copied to clipboard by python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31685914/accessing-text-copied-to-clipboard-by-python)

Is there a way I can do it using Selenium Webdriver methods in Python?

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

`tkinter` comes in shipped by default with python3, contrary to what I was thinking, and using it is pretty simple:

My adding of last  2 code-lines to the previous code mentioned in my question, worked like charm:

```
''' I will change time.sleep() later to appropriate WebdriverWait. This is just for test. '''
''' This also means that I will have to save the copied password from clipboard within 10seconds, '''
''' before the window closes '''
time.sleep(20)
copy_button = self.chrome_driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="button__container__not-show-spinner"]/div[@class="button__text"]')
copy_button.click()
root = tk.Tk()
print(root.clipboard_get())
```

Ofcourse you have to import the `tkinter` for this to work, and in my case this is the import statement I used:

```
import tkinter as tk
```