# Cannot access clipboard in Heroku (Selenium webscraper - python)

Tags: python, selenium, heroku, web-scraping, pyclipper

I have deployed a very basic webscraper in heroku to periodically press a button, which then copies a link to the browsers clipboard, which I then store in a variable using:

`text = pyclip.paste()`

This works fine on my local machine that's running windows 10, however when I deploy it to heroku I get the following error:

```
2021-08-17T12:57:38.512015+00:00 app[worker.1]: text = pyclip.paste()
2021-08-17T12:57:38.512026+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyclip/__init__.py", line 
41, in paste
2021-08-17T12:57:38.512144+00:00 app[worker.1]: raise ClipboardSetupException("Could not setup clipboard").with_traceback(_CLIPBOARD_EXCEPTION_TB)
2021-08-17T12:57:38.512154+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyclip/__init__.py", line 
19, in <module>
2021-08-17T12:57:38.512316+00:00 app[worker.1]: DEFAULT_CLIPBOARD = detect_clipboard()
2021-08-17T12:57:38.512339+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyclip/util.py", line 30, 
in detect_clipboard
2021-08-17T12:57:38.512437+00:00 app[worker.1]: return XclipClipboard()
2021-08-17T12:57:38.512447+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyclip/xclip_clip.py", line 29, in __init__
2021-08-17T12:57:38.512561+00:00 app[worker.1]: raise ClipboardSetupException(
2021-08-17T12:57:38.512595+00:00 app[worker.1]: pyclip.base.ClipboardSetupException: Could not setup clipboard
2021-08-17T12:57:38.656967+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-08-17T12:57:38.755984+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
```

I am guessing that the dyno dosen't really have a clipboard in place, to which the webdriver can then send the link, and from which pyclip can then retrive it.

Does anyone know a workaround to this or how to setup and access a clipboard when deploying the scraper?

**Edit 1**
I also installed the *heroku-community/apt* buildpack and then included *copyq* in the Aptfile to attempt to setup a clipboard while building the app, but to no avail. Does anyone think Docker is a good idea?

Answer (score 0):

okay as a workaround you could pass `ctrl + v`, if you are using **Selenium** and have **web elements.**

```
pyperclip.copy("some text")
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('some xpath').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + "v")
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, however this would not solve the problem because I want to store the copied text/link inside a variable for further processing.  So the challenge here is to extract the data from the webdrivers clipboard, and I can do that locally using pyclip/tkinter but not inside a dyno :(

Comment: No how did you get the data ? I would presume that it was either .text or get attribute with innerHtml right ?

Comment: I initially followed this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64720945/python-selenium-code-to-save-text-in-a-variable-from-clipboard-which-is-copied-t 
Then I also realized that I could use pyclip and that it would work. The variable takes in the clipboard data as a string in my code.