# Python translation of R's read.table 'text' argument

Tags: python, pandas

In `R` if someone on SO posts a data frame as text:

```
  x y
1 1 a
2 2 b
3 3 c
```

One would highlight and copy the data frame as is, and paste it into R to recreate it:

```
df <- read.table(text="  x y
1 1 a
2 2 b
3 3 c", header=TRUE)
```

What is the equivalent in Python to copy table-like data and paste to work with?

Comment: What will you be using this for afterwards and what is the OS? I ask because you can do `pd.read_clipboard()` in `pandas` and there is this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/101128/how-do-i-read-text-from-the-windows-clipboard-from-python

Comment: After, reshaping and manipulation of the data would be done. Your suggestion worked really well. Thank you. if you would like to add an answer, please do. The answer linked does not have a `pandas` solution.

Answer (score 0):

As @EdChurn suggested in the comments, the task is very simple and straightforward with `pandas`:

1. Copy the data from the original source with Ctrl+C (or other method)
2. In Python:

   ```
   import pandas as pd
   df = pd.read_clipboard()
   >>> df

      x  y
   1  1  a
   2  2  b
   3  3  c
   ```